# Making case-insensitive query on JSON field using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

My data is stored as a JSON array in the `from` column as follows:

```
[{"emailAddress": {"name": "Test", "address": "example@example.com"}}]
```

I want to "case-insensitively" search in that column. This is what I've tried so far (without success):

```
->orWhereRaw('lower(from->"$[*].emailAddress.name") like lower(?)', ["%{$searchTerm}%"]);

->orWhereRaw('lower(from->"$.emailAddress.name") like lower(?)', ["%{$searchTerm}%"]);

->orWhereRaw('lower(from->emailAddress"$.name") like lower(?)', ["%{$searchTerm}%"]);
```

All with the same error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from->"$[*].emailAddress.name") like lower(?)' at line 1
```

The "case-sensitive query"

```
->orWhere('from->emailAddress->name', 'like', "{$searchTerm}");
```

**works** without any problem.

I am using MySql 5.7.25 and Laravel 5.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word `from` is a special keyword in SQL and must be quoted with backticks. The version of the query most likely to work is:

```
lower(`from`->"$[*].emailAddress.name") like lower(?)
```

Comment: Thank you @Joni! Error is gone, however do not have the expected result (=0).. This is how the query gets binded: ```select count(*) from `messages` where lower(`from`->"$[*].emailAddress.name") like lower('%te%')``` and I do have `Test` as a value in my db..